# Visually Explain the Pythagorean Theorem

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, geometry

A common visual explanation of the Pythagorean theorem is as such:

[image: 3 boxes]

The squares are meant to represent the side length's squared, and the areas of `a + b = c`, just like the Pythagorean theorem says.

This part is what you have to show.

## Your task

- You will get two integers as input, meant to represent sides `a` and `b` of a right triangle (ex. `3, 4`).
- You will then make squares out of the lengths `a`, `b`, and `c` out of the `#` character. For example here is 3:

```
###
###
###
```

- You will then format these into a math equation that explains the particular Pythagorean triplet:

```
             #####
      ####   #####
###   ####   #####
###   ####   #####
### + #### = #####
```

- Notice how the `=` and `+` signs have spaces on both sides and how everything is on the bottom.
- You will never get values for `a` and `b` that make `c` non-integral.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in **bytes** wins!

## Test Cases

(more coming once I have time, these are really hard to make by hand)

```
3, 4
             #####
      ####   #####
###   ####   #####
###   ####   #####
### + #### = #####

6, 8
                    ##########
                    ##########
         ########   ##########
         ########   ##########
######   ########   ##########
######   ########   ##########
######   ########   ##########
######   ########   ##########
######   ########   ##########
###### + ######## = ##########

4, 3
             #####
####         #####
####   ###   #####
####   ###   #####
#### + ### = #####

5, 12
                       #############
        ############   #############
        ############   #############
        ############   #############
        ############   #############
        ############   #############
        ############   #############
        ############   #############
#####   ############   #############
#####   ############   #############
#####   ############   #############
#####   ############   #############
##### + ############ = #############
```

Comment: What about inputs where the third number would not be an integer? For example, given inputs of 1 and 1, the third side would be sqrt(2).

Comment: @bmarks "You will never get values for a and b that make c non-integral."

Comment: Is `b` going to always be larger than `a`?

Comment: @vihan nope, adding that to the tests

Comment: `a + b = c`? I don't think that was the result Pythagoras came up with...

Comment: @RetoKoradi well the *areas of the squares* `a+b=c`

Comment: If `a`, `b` and `c` are defined as the areas of the squares, then the examples are incorrect.

Comment: You should add another nice test case, like 5 + 12 = 13.

Comment: @mbomb007 I will now that I have my reference solution, yayyy ^.^

Comment: Note: this is not "a visual explanation of the Pythagorean theorem". This is **the** Pythagorean theorem. It was originally formulated exactly this way: geometrically. They didn't even know about square roots, even more interesting, Pythagoras himself didn't believe in the existence of irrational numbers. This means Pythagoras thought that sqrt(2) can be exactly represented by the division of two finite integers. The original theorem is what we now call the "visual representation"

Comment: @vsz Actually, based on my understanding - the Pythagoreans would have realized that there are no integers whose ratio is sqrt(2).  From this, they would have concluded that sqrt(2) does not exist.  In other words, they would have thought it is impossible to draw a line of length sqrt(2).  The Pythagorean theorem apparently caused problems, because they knew how to construct a right triangle with sides 1,1,x.  The Pythagorean theorem showed that x=sqrt(2) actually exists.  Legend has it they drowned the person who discovered this and then swore everyone to secrecy.

Comment: Can we use a different character instead of `#`? What about leading/trailing whitespace?

Answer (score 19):

## Pyth, <strike>35</strike> <strike>32</strike> <strike>31</strike> 30 bytes

```
j_.ts.i.imm*d\#d+Qs.aQ"+="mk4d
```

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j_.ts.imm*d%5C%23d%2BQs.aQm%5Bkdk)%22%2B%3D%22d&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=3%2C+4%0A6%2C+8%0A4%2C+3%0A5%2C+12&debug=0)

Comment: You can save a byte by using `.i` to add the blank lines instead: `j_.ts.i.imm*d\#d+Qs.aQ"+="mk4d`

Answer (score 14):

## CJam, 49 bytes

```
" +   = "S/3/[q~_2$mh:H]_'#f*:a.*.\:+SH*f.e|zW%N*
```

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22%20%2B%20%20%20%3D%20%22S%2F3%2F%5Bq%7E_2%24mh%3AH%5D_%27%23f*%3Aa.*.%5C%3A%2BSH*f.e%7CzW%25N*&input=3%204).

#### How it works

```
" +   = "S/3/ e# Split at spaces, then into chunks of length 3.
              e# This pushes [["" "+" ""] ["" "=" ""]].
[             e#
  q~          e# Read and interpret all input from STDIN.
  _2$         e# Copy both integers.
  mh          e# Calculate the hypotenuse of the triangle with those catheti.
  :H          e# Save the result in H.
]             e# Collect catheti and hypotenuse in an array.
_'#f*         e# Copy and replace each length with a string of that many hashes.
:a            e# Wrap each string in an array.
.*            e# Vectorized repetition. Turns strings into square arrays.
.\            e# Interleave with the string of operators.
:+            e# Concatenate to form an array of strings.
SH*           e# Push a string of spaces of length H.
f.e|          e# Mapped vectorized logical OR; pads all strings with spaces to
              e# length H.
zW%           e# Zip and reverse; rotates the array.
N*            e# Join the strings, separating by linefeeds.
```

Answer (score 13):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>155</s> <s>134</s> <s>140</s> 129 bytes

```
(n,m)=>eval("for(o='',q=(b,s)=>' #'[z<b|0].repeat(b)+(z?'   ':s),z=i=Math.hypot(n,m);z--;)o+=q(n,' + ')+q(m,' = ')+q(i,'')+`\n`")
```

I've rewritten this with `for`. Lots of golfing still...

If something isn't working, let me know. I'll fix it in the morning.

**Tested on Safari Nightly**

### Ungolfed:

```
(n,m)=>
   Array(
     z=Math.hypot(n,m)
   ).fill()
   .map((l,i)=>
      (q=(j,s)=>
        (z-i<=j?'#':' ')
        .repeat(j)+
         (z-i-1?' ':s)
      )
      (n,`+`)+
      q(m,`=`)+
      q(z,'')
   ).join`
   `
```

## Explanation:

(Not updated) but still accurate enough.

```
(n,m)=> // Function with two arguments n,m
   Array( // Create array of length...
    z=Math.hypot(n,m) // Get sqrt(n^2+m^2) and store in z
   ).fill() // Fill array so we can loop
   .map((l,i) => // Loop z times, take l, and i (index)
     (q=j=>( // Create function q with argument j
      z-i<=j? // If z-i is less than or equal to j...
        '#' // Use '#'
      : // OR
        ' ' // Use space
      ).repeat(j) // Repeat the character j times
     )(n) // Run with n
   + // Add to string
   ` ${ // Space
      (b=z-i-1)? // If this isn't the last line...
       ' ' // Return ' '
      : // Otherwise
       '+' // Plus
    } ${ // Space
      q(m) // run function q with arg m
    } ${ // Space
      b? // If b
       ' ' // Return space
      : // Otherwise
        '=' // '='
    }` + // Add to...
    '#'.repeat(z) // Repeat hashtag, z times
  ).join` // Join the new array with new lines
  `
```

## DEMO

ES5 version **Input must be valid sets of numbers**:

```js
function _taggedTemplateLiteral(e,t){return Object.freeze(Object.defineProperties(e,{raw:{value:Object.freeze(t)}}))}var _templateObject=_taggedTemplateLiteral(["\n"],["\n"]),t=function(e,t){return Array(z=Math.sqrt(e*e+t*t)).fill().map(function(r,n){return(q=function(e,t){return(z-n<=e?"#":" ").repeat(e)+(z-n-1?" ":t)})(e,"+")+q(t,"=")+q(z,"")}).join(_templateObject)};
// Demo
document.getElementById('go').onclick=function(){
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = t(+document.getElementById('input').value,
                                                 +document.getElementById('input2').value)
};
```

```html
<div style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;"><h2 style="font-family:sans-serif">Visually Explaining the Pythagorean Theorem</h2><div><div  style="background-color:#EFEFEF;border-radius:4px;padding:10px;"><input placeholder="Number 1" style="resize:none;border:1px solid #DDD;" id="input"><input placeholder="Number 2" style="resize:none;border:1px solid #DDD;" id="input2"><button id='go'>Run!</button></div><br><div style="background-color:#EFEFEF;border-radius:4px;padding:10px;"><span style="font-family:sans-serif;">Output:</span><br><pre id="output" style="background-color:#DEDEDE;padding:1em;border-radius:2px;overflow-x:auto;"></pre></div></div></div>
```

Comment: +1, but there's a small issue as the OP says: "Notice how the = and + signs have spaces on both sides and how everything is on the bottom."

Comment: The snippet isn't working on Firefox 40.0.3 (Windows 7x64 SP1).

Comment: Snippet not working in Chromium 44 Linux x64

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel You need to make sure the numbers you're entering are valid, otherwise this won't work.

Comment: This works with `3,4`, `4,3` and `5,12`, but not with `3,5`, `5,3`, `4,5`, `5,4` and similars. I think this was example-driven: only works with the values on the examples.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Those latter cases aren't necessary to handle correctly, though: "You will never get values for `a` and `b` that make `c` non-integral."

Comment: The blank separation is 3 spaces, not 1

Comment: @edc65 I've updated the code but not the demo yet

Comment: +1 nice use of eval. Hint: `(z<b?'#':' ')` -> `' #'[z<b|0]`

Comment: @edc65 definitely, that saved two bytes!

Answer (score 13):

## Python 2, <s>134</s> 100 bytes

```
a,b=input()
i=c=int(abs(a+b*1j))
while i:print"# "[i>a]*a," +"[i<2],"# "[i>b]*b," ="[i<2],"#"*c;i-=1
```

[Try it online.](http://ideone.com/Yw7JOz)

The program takes input as comma-separated integers, calculates the hypotenuse using Python's built-in complex numbers, then loops down from that value calculating and printing each line as it goes. The main golfing trick is using string indexing in place of conditionals to select `#`/`+`/`=` vs space.

*Edit:* The first version was a victim of some serious over-engineering--this one is both simpler and much shorter.

Comment: I just got the same thing, having taken a while to realize it's shorter to just repeat `"# "[i>a]*a` instead of doing it for each variable.

Answer (score 12):

## Julia, <s>121</s> <s>114</s> 112 bytes

```julia
f(a,b)=for i=1:(c=isqrt(a^2+b^2)) g(x,t)=(i>c-x?"#":" ")^x*(i<c?"  ":t)" ";println(g(a," +")g(b," =")g(c,""))end
```

Ungolfed:

```julia
function f(a,b)
    # Compute the hypotenuse length
    c = isqrt(a^2 + b^2)

    # Write the lines in a loop
    for i = 1:c
        # Make a function for constructing the blocks
        g(x,t) = (i <= c - x ? " " : "#")^x * (i < c ? "  " : t) " "

        println(g(a," +") g(b," =") g(c,""))
    end
end
```

Fixed issue and saved 2 bytes thanks to Glen O.

Answer (score 8):

## Pyth, <s>51</s> 49 bytes

```
AQJs.aQLj*b]*b\#;j_MCm_.[d\ Jcj[yJb\=byHb\+byG))b
```

Expects input in the form `[3,4]`.

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=AQJs.aQLj*b]*b%5C%23%3Bj_MCm_.[d%5C+Jcj[yJb%5C%3DbyHb%5C%2BbyG%29%29b&input=[3%2C+4])

`AQ` - assigns input to `G, H`

`Js.a,GH` - calculates hypotenuse as `J`

`Lj*b]*b\#;` - defines `y(b)` as making a square of size `b` (elsewhere in the code, `b` means newline)

`j_MCm_.[d\ Jcj[yJb\=byHb\+byG))b` - Creates the squares, pads with spaces, and transposes

Saved two bytes thanks to Maltysen.

Comment: I don't know exactly what your code does, but I'm pretty sure it can benefit from `.i`nterlace instead of all those lists.

Comment: @Maltysen To your last comment, actually I can't, because the first appearance of `J` is inside a lambda, which gets evaluated _after_ `J` is first used.

Comment: ah, didn't see that. Another thing: `*]` can be replaced with `m`

Answer (score 5):

## C, 176 bytes

C is not going to win this, but the fun is worth it.

```
#define A(x,y)for(j=x;j--;)putchar("# "[i+1>x]);printf(i?"   ":" "#y" ");
i;j;main(a,b,c){for(c=scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);a*a+b*b>c*c;c++);for(i=c;i--;puts("")){A(a,+)A(b,=)A(c,)}}
```

Pretty printed:

```
#define A(x,y)for(j=x;j--;)putchar("# "[i+1>x]);printf(i?"   ":" "#y" ");
i;j;
main(a,b,c)
{
    for(c=scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);a*a+b*b>c*c;c++);
    for(i=c;i--;puts(""))
    {
        A(a,+)
        A(b,=)
        A(c,)
    }
}
```

gcc enables us to pass third parameter to main (an array of environment variables), so we take advantage of it to use it for our purpose.

The

```
for(c=scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);a*a+b*b>c*c++;);
```

would be equivalent to

```
scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
for(c=2;a*a+b*b>c*c++;);
```

because `scanf` returns the number of successfully scaned parameters.

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 24 bytes

```
⊞θ₂ΣＸθ²Ｆ =+«←←←ι←Ｇ↑←↓⊟θ#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gtDhDo1BHIbiwNLEoNSg/v0QjuDRXIyC/PLUIJG6kCQTWXGn5RQoaSgq22kqaCtVcnL75ZakaVj6paSVAOTReQFFmXgmEq6OQiUU@P6cyPT9Pwyq0QEcBqszKJb88T0chIL9Ao1BTR0FJWQmosvb//@hoYx0Fk9jY/7plOQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as an array of two elements. Explanation:

```
⊞θ₂ΣＸθ²
```

Append the hypotenuse to the inputs.

```
Ｆ =+«
```

Loop over the characters that appear to the right of each square in reverse order.

```
←←←ι←
```

Print that character leftwards with spacing.

```
Ｇ↑←↓⊟θ#
```

Pop the last number from the array and print a square of `#`s of that size.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Whoa, what an oversight! Should be fixed now.

Comment: Lyxal has a better alternate explanation [here](https://gist.github.com/Lyxal/1fb606f9b40536aa1a9f09a6d4fd4684). You should totally edit that into your answer.

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 134

```
->a,b{c=((a**2+b**2)**0.5).round
c.times{|i|
d=i<c-1?'  ':'+='
puts (c-i>a ?' ':?#)*a+" #{d[0]}  #{(c-i>b ?' ':?#)*b} #{d[1]} "+?#*c}}
```

simple line by line approach.

Below in test program, with symbol changed to @ to help avoid confusting with the syntax `#{....}` ("string interpolation") used to insert expressions into a string. Each input should be given on a different line.

```
f=->a,b{c=((a**2+b**2)**0.5).round
c.times{|i|
d=i<c-1?'  ':'+='
puts (c-i>a ?' ':?@)*a+" #{d[0]}  #{(c-i>b ?' ':?@)*b} #{d[1]} "+?@*c}}

A=gets.to_i
B=gets.to_i
f.call(A,B)
```

Comment: I don't know Ruby, but I'm guessing this can get shorter, since Ruby solutions often beat Python solutions (in my anecdotal experience).  For starters, `a*a+b*b` should cut two bytes from the computation of `c`.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>33</s> 29 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

-3 due to my extensions of Dyalog APL.

Anonymous prefix lambda:

```apl
{⊖⍕,' +=',⍪{⍵ ⍵⍴⍕#}¨⍵,√+/⍵*2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/v/pR17RHvVN11BW0bdV1HvWuqn7Uu1UBiB/1bgGKK9ceWgHk6DzqmKWtD2RoGdX@T3vUNuFRb9@jvqme/o@6mg@tN37UNhHICw5yBpIhHp7B/9MUjBVMuNIUzBQsgKSJgjGQNFUwNAIA)

`{`…`}` "dfn"; `⍵` is the argument (side lengths)

`⍵*2` square

`+/` sum

`√` square-root

`⍵,` prepend argument

`{`…`}¨` apply the following anonymous lambda to each

`#` root namespace

`⍕` format as text

`⍵ ⍵⍴` use argument twice to **r**eshape into matrix with those dimensions.

`⍪` make into column

`' ++=',` prepend these three characters to the three rows

`,` ravel (combine rows into list)

`⍕` format as text

`⊖` flip upside-down

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>178</s> <s>170</s> 168 bytes

Input is GET parameters `x` and `y`. Unfortunately I can't seem to golf those repeating strings.

```
<?php for(@$i=$z=hypot($x=$_GET[x],$y=$_GET[y]),@$s=str_repeat;$i;$i--)@print$s($i<=$x?~Ü:~ß,$x).(($l=$i==1)?~ßÔß:~ßßß).$s($i<=$y?~Ü:~ß,$y).($l?~ßÂß:~ßßß).$s(~Ü,$z).~õ;
```

- Saved 8 bytes by inverting all my strings and dropping the quotes.
- Saved 2 bytes by replacing the condition `$i>0` with `$i`

Not sure why PHP doesn't like `@echo` so I had to sacrifice 1 byte with `@print`.

In case SE screws up the encoding, this is meant to be encoded in Windows-1252 (not UTF8).

Comment: `echo` vs `print`. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094118/reference-comparing-phps-print-and-echo

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>139</s> <s>137</s> 135 bytes

<sup>-2 thanks to ASCII-only</sup>
<sup>-2 thanks to Mazzy</sup>

```powershell
param($a,$b)($c=[math]::sqrt($a*$a+$b*$b))..1|%{(($m=" ","#")[$_-le$a]*$a)," +"[$_-eq1],($m[$_-le$b]*$b)," ="[$_-eq1],("#"*$c)-join" "}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxBCoMwFET3niL8/pYkRkFaShFyEgklSsSKVo1CF9azp9/SRXfDvDczDi/n58Z1XcBar2G03vYcrcJScKx00dulMXk@T36hWqKNsZQERZpm7@PKOfYaGCg4gCjwnnQOrSFNKGAx7I2bMqNI@9HS7HOi@o/SWmIlknZ4POltC1t0wpqd2SUC@MYbu0bhAw)

Calculating $c hurt and there's probably a better way to conditionally swap between `#` and . Builds a list of chunks and joins them together while conditionally adding the signs.

Comment: there is a redundant brackets in `$m=(" ","#")`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxBCoMwFET3niL8/pYkRkFaShFyEgklSsSKVo1CF9azp9/SRXfDvDczDi/n58Z1XcBar2G03vYcrcJScKx00dulMXk@T36hWqKNsZQERZpm7@PKOfYaGCg4gCjwnnQOrSFNKGAx7I2bMqNI@9HS7HOi@o/SWmIlknZ4POltC1t0wpqd2SUC@MYbu0bhAw "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @mazzy Ha ha, whoops

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), `L`, <s>47</s> <s>43</s> 38 bytes (old codepage)

```
λ\#*wnř;:£f⍎÷ð\+ð?¥f⍎÷ð\=ð??Ķĵ∑√I¥f⍎÷W
```

This was *intense*.

Also, according to code-golf's statistics, only a small percentage of people who see my answers actually upvote them. So if you enjoy this answer, consider upvoting, it's free, and you can change your mind at any time (given you have ≥2k rep). Enjoy the answer.

### Explained

```python
λn\#*wnř;:£f⍎ðJ\+JðJ?¥f⍎JðJ\=JðJ??Ķĵ∑√I¥f⍎J

λ                                               # Start a lambda that:
 n\#*                                           #   Repeats the character "#" n times THEN
     w                                          #   Wraps that into a stack AND
      nř                                        #   Repeats the list n times
        ;                                       # Close lambda
         :£f                                    # Assign the lambda to variable 'f' leaving an extra copy
            ⍎                                   # Apply that lambda to the first input
             ðJ\+JðJ                            # Append " ", "+" and " " to the result from above
                    ?¥f⍎                        # Apply the lambda to the second input
                        J                       # Add it to the current list
                         ðJ\=Jð                 # Append " ", "=" and " " to the result from above
                               ??Ķ              # Pair the two inputs into a list
                                  ĵ∑            # Square each number and sum the list (a^2 + b^2)
                                    √I          # Square root that number and convert it to an integer
                                      ¥f⍎       # Apply the lambda to that result (c)
                                         J      # And add it to the big list
                                                # The L flag then auto vertical joins the list and outputs it
```

Comment: -1 just because you asked me to upvote

Comment: good meming sir

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 78 bytes

```
q~_2f#~+mQ+ee_2=~e>f{\~@1$-S*\'#*+_'#e=\a*_0=,S*@"+= "=1$,(S*\+1$a\a@a+++~}zN*
```

It first computes the hypotenuse (H), then, for each side (S), it builds an array of S lines made of: `H-S` spaces + `S` dashes. Finally, it transposes the matrix.

[Demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~_2f%23~%2BmQ%2Bee_2%3D~e%3Ef%7B%5C~%401%24-S*%5C'%23*%2B_'%23e%3D%5Ca*_0%3D%2CS*%40%22%2B%3D%20%22%3D1%24%2C(S*%5C%2B1%24a%5Ca%40a%2B%2B%2B~%7DzN*&input=%5B6%208%5D)

Answer (score 2):

## Lua5.2, <del>257</del> <del>241</del> <del>227</del> 222 bytes

```
r=io.read
a=r"*n"b=r"*n"c=math.sqrt(a^2+b^2)d=a+b
w=io.write
for i=1,c do
for j=0,d+c+5 do
w((j>d+5 or(i>c-b and j>a+2 and j<d+3)or(i>c-a and j<a))and"#"or(i==c and(j==a+1 and"+"or(j==d+4 and"="or" "))or" "))end
w"\n"end
```

- Edit1: Simplified reading
- Edit2: Removed more whitespaces
- Edit3: aliases abstraction of `io` functions inspired by [another answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55923/13223)

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, 28 bytes

Takes input as an array of integers.

```
pUx²¬)ËÆDç'#
í"+="¬ûR3)c ·z3
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=cFV4sqwpy8ZE5ycjCu0iKz0irPtSMyljILd6Mw==&input=WzMsNF0=)

```
                    :Implicit input of array U=[a,b]
pUx²¬)ËÆDç'#
p                   :Push
 U ²                :  Square each element in U
  x                 :  Reduce by addition
    ¬               :  Square root
     )              :End push
      Ë             :Map each D
       Æ            :  Map the range [0,D)
        Dç'#        :    Repeat "#" D times
í"+="¬ûR3)c ·z3
í                   :Interleave
 "+="¬              :  Split the string "+=" to an array of characters
      û             :  Centre pad each
       R3           :    With newlines to length 3
         )          :End interleave
          c         :Flatten
            ·       :Join with newlines
             z3     :Rotate clockwise 270 degrees
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>221</s>, 194 bytes

This feels way too long.  This version just loops to construct the string.

EDIT:  Ascii-Only with a nice -27 byte golf using the string constructor for serial char additions!  Also, ty for pointing out I was using Math.Sqrt not System.Math.Sqrt.  This has been adjusted!

```cs
(a,b)=>{int c=(int)System.Math.Sqrt(a*a+b*b),j=c;var s="";while(j>0)s+=new string(j>a?' ':'#',a)+(j>1?"   ":" + ")+new string(j>b?' ':'#',b)+(j-->1?"   ":" = ")+new string('#',c)+"\n";return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5BSwMxEIXv@yuGeNik2S1W8NKY7UHwZEHowYuXSTZtU9KsJtkWKf3ta1aLWBmYYeZ9vHk61roLZuij9RtYfcZk9qLQDmOEl9BtAu5PBcB7r5zVEBOmPA6dbWGJ1lM2igBPvdcP1qcKvltMIbs10IIcKFaKyeaUBdCS5sF@vkyXmLbT1UdIFCfI1USxaie1OGCAKAkRx611hu6aWxa59OZ4sc0XXJRQzsubskLG8z5bkByCzAlwIIxfseqXVSNb139o@Y8eKc04efNEBJP64CGK8yCKS@LHzsfOmelrsMk8W29oS@@r2R1joiiKc65h3dvWRXRr/AI)

Comment: remember the ending semicolon isn't needed, and also `System.Math` not `Math` if you're not using interactive

Comment: [211?](https://tio.run/##bYw9D8IgFEX/ygsO5Ulr1MSlSLs56eTg4gIUlcZgBKqD8bfXNn4kTZxe7r3nPB0yHWy7apxeVpdGnU0K3xuit@5YQAWipTJVKIrHTXrQYiPjabK9@kjlWDI1Vsj7IQhC@OHiaR9qoXldTDkGJpy5f77ReilkmYySPIEkpdZFlMi6dl4SYEByAgAE2dBQQ0P9DPHX6OA3qHswy3q04/aOIPcmNt5B4M@W77yNZm2doRVdpLM5Im9f)

Comment: [187?](https://tio.run/##XcyxDoIwEAbgV7nUgR4tRkxcqIXNzcnBxaUtREpME9sig/HZEYwx6nJ//rsvZ0Jmgh13vTNb6yKH1wjRW3cuoQY5UsU1yvI@HcBIOgXuVWyXh6uPVKWK6VQj76QRN@UhSELE0NpLQ7tyhYFJ1wzvf9NGVQkkRbJIuEI29bwiAEAKAgwIsh@rP1bPNsu@tPzTszLIyMkR4ZvYewdBPEZx9DY2tKYbnq8RxfgE)

Comment: One thing, I'd [remove all using directives](https://tio.run/##XY5BSwMxEIXv@yuGeNik2V2s4KUx24PgyYLQgxcvk2zapqRZTbItUvrb16wUURmYx8z7Zng61roPZtQOY4SX0G8DHs4FwPugnNUQE6Ysx952sELrKZtMgPVnTObQPA1eP1ifKvhuMQXrty10IEeKlWKyPWcDtKRZ2PVohWnXrD9CojhDrmaKVXupxREDREmIOO2sM3Tf3rLIpTen69u8wWUJ5aK8KStkPM/zJclZyIIAB8L4H1b9sGpi6/oXLf/RE6UZJ2@eiGDSEDxEcRlFcU382PvYO9O8BpvMs/WGdvS@mt8xJoqiuOQaN4PtXES3wS8) to make sure I didn't make a mistake

Comment: Oh and since you no longer have the ternary version I don't think you should mention it anymore

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>38</s> 34 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
nOtª©Å1'#×ζε®×R„= NĀèð.øý}»R„=+`.;
```

Takes the input as pair of integers (i.e. `[3,4]`).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/z7/k0KpDKw@3GqorH55@btu5rYfWHZ4e9Khhnq2C35GGwysOb9A7vOPw3tpDu8GC2gl61v//RxvrKJjEAgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaBkX3l4go6Sf2kJhKvzP8@/5NCqQysPtxqqKx@efm7bua2H1h2eHvSoYZ6tgt@RhsMrDm/QO7zj8N7aQ7vBgtoJetb/dQ5ts/8fHW2sYxKroxBtpmMBokx0jEGUqY6hUWwsAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
n            # Take the square of each value in the (implicit) input-list
 O           # Take the sum of that list
  t          # Take the square-root of that sum
   ª         # Append it to the (implicit) input-list
             #  i.e. [3,4] → [3,4,5.0]
    ©        # Store it in the register (without popping)
Å1           # Change each value to an inner list of that amount of 1s
  '#×       '# And then each 1 to a "#"
             #  → [["#","#","#"],["#","#","#","#"],["#","#","#","#","#"]]
     ζ       # Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns, with space as default filler
             #  → [["#","#","#"],["#","#","#"],["#","#","#"],[" ","#","#"],[" "," ","#"]]
ε            # Map the inner lists to:
 ®           #  Push the list from the register
  ×          #  Repeat the characters that many times
             #   i.e. [" ","#","#"] and [3,4,5.0] → ["   ","####","#####"]
   R         #  Reverse this list
 „=          #  Push string "= "
    NĀ       #  Push the map-index truthified (0 remains 0; everything else becomes 1)
             #   i.e. 0 → 0
             #   i.e. 3 → 1
      è      #  Use it to index into the string
       ð.ø   #  Surround it with spaces
             #   → "=" → " = "
             #   → " " → "   "
          ý  #  Join the map-list together with this string as delimiter
             #   → "#####   ####      "
}»           # After the map, join everything by newlines
             #  → "##### = #### = ###\n#####   ####   ###\n#####   ####   ###\n#####   ####      \n#####             "
  R          # Reverse the string
             #  → "             #####\n      ####   #####\n###   ####   #####\n###   ####   #####\n### = #### = #####"
   „=+`.;    # And replace the first "=" with "+"
             #  → "             #####\n      ####   #####\n###   ####   #####\n###   ####   #####\n### + #### = #####"
             # (after which the the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: `DnOt©)˜ε'#×y.Dðy×®y-.D)R}ø»` was my attempt until I noticed the `+` and `=`.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Yeah, those three spaces and `+` and `=` are indeed responsible for the most part of the code. Btw, you can golf 2 bytes in your approach by replacing `DnOt©)˜` with `nOt©ª`, as I did in my current answer. :) I like your use of `.D`, though.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 99 bytes

```perl6
{$!=sqrt $^a²+$^b²;flip map({map {[' ','#'][$^d>$_]x$d,' =+ '.comb[!$_*++$ ]},$!,$b,$a},^$!)X"
"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcfRCoIwFIDhe5/izA7NtUNQWjeyniMYTmYqBEqmXSRjL@Uj@GIrCLr5@f6hGbtz6GfYtqAgOGRqeo4vQGPXRaKp1iVvu/sAvR0S9w04zYET3/BCo6kvWBZvrImDksD3t0dfaYblTkqEwhMyworQejLIxDWOYh8mO0ObpJSJPPr5RIfjfzJKRR4@)

Anonymous code block that takes two numbers and returns the full string with a leading newline and three leading spaces and one trailing on each line.

If we can use other characters instead of `#`, then I can save a byte by replacing `'#'` with `\*`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 36 bytes

```
↔T' `+₁√ṁ□¹`+C1" = "JC1" + "m₁
SRR'#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HblBB1hQTtR02NjzpmPdzZ@GjawkM7E7SdDZUUbBWUvEC0toJSLlCeKzgoSF35////0cY6JrEA)

This can be made shorter if I can find a good way to add the symbols in.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>122</s> 119 bytes

-3 thanks to ceilingcat

```c
#define P(n);for(i=0;i*i++<n;puts(""))for(j=0;j*j++<n;)putchar(35);puts(
i,j;f(a,b){P(a*a)"+")P(b*b)"=")P(a*a+b*b)"");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzBDsIgDIbvPEWDlxZmMjWe6t5hrwC4KSSiwe207NmRsYs9tH@/r6k7PpzL@XAfRh8H6DESj@@EvmvZK6/1LfJnnr4oJdEmQhFBhSqoGPc0CS9X2q@EbwKPaBpLS49GGZJaUo9WWZLdlgrTdZPEa/ZxgpfxEQkWIaDURgx0cG3AlnE6c8W17Y//QBqmOUVoWaz5Bw)